# What's the name of the fibrous strands that hold the seeds in a pumpkin?

Tags: botany, nomenclature

If you cut open a pumpkin, the seeds are suspended inside the pumpkin by some fibrous, slimey strands. You can see them in the middle of this sliced-open pumpkin:

[image: Image of inside of a pumpkin]

I'm writing a post for the [Cooking.SE blog](http://cooking.blogoverflow.com), and am trying to find out the proper botanical term. Someone suggested that might be called the endocarp, but I want to make sure and also see if there is a more specific term.

### Edit

In "Morpho-Physiological Aspects of Productivity and Quality in Squash and Pumpkins (Cucurbita spp.)" §C.1, I see this:

> In the central portion of the fruit, a mass of tough fibers, together with vascular strands connected to the seeds, comprise the **placental tissue.** The endocarp is made up of small, thin-walled cells that form a membranous tissue that adheres to seed, becoming a transparent skin on dried seeds. **(emphasis added)**

Am I reading correctly that the name for this part of the pumpkin is "placental tissue", and that the endocarp is just a thin layer on the seeds themselves?

Comment: I have also found some sources that suggested this is the placenta, but couldn't find a good example like a figure with an arrow pointing to that and saying "placenta". Googling "pumpkin placenta" gives bubkes.

Comment: @Bitwise if you try "fruit placental tissue", you get more results... I think pumpkins are fruit from a botanical standpoint, right?

Comment: They are indeed berries.

Answer (score 3):

This part of the fruit is called "Endocarp". It does not become more specific as that, as far as I know.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fruit_anatomy

Comment: From the article I quoted in the edit, it sounds like the endocarp is actually the thin film directly attached to the seed, not the fibrous stuff around it. Am I reading the article incorrectly?

Comment: According to this site, the stringy bits inside a pumpkin is called the endocarp ( http://www.cls.zju.edu.cn/sub/fulab/plant_Antomy/plant/fruit/index.html )

Comment: @leonardo Where do you see that on the site? I can't find pumpkins mentioned anywhere. Wikipedia lets me know pumpkins are berries, and that site describes the mesocarp and endocarp as the "fleshy or juicy tissue", so that sounds like the part of the pumpkin you eat...

Comment: I was looking at squash in general.

Comment: Also, Wikipedia would inform you that pumpkins are indeed squash (not berries).

Comment: @leonardo http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry lists pumpkins. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squash_%28plant%29 says that squash are berries. So now I'm even more confused...

Comment: @derobert - odd, the first sentence of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumpkin is that it is a gourd-like squash. I don't really know.

Comment: "Berries" are just a certain classification of the anatomy of a fruit, it has, as far as i know, nothing to do with the phylogeny. Apples are also berries, as well as Bananas and Oranges.

Comment: "Berry" is a good example of a perfectly normal English word that has been used with a different but related meaning by scientists (in this case botanists), and that pedants delight in pretending therefore doesn't have it's original (less precise) meaning. So pumpkins are certainly a kind of squash, and squash are generally considered berries by botanists AFAIK. Obviously they aren't considered berries by civilian English-speakers, but that's because normal English-speakers aren't interested in their anatomy.

Comment: ... so in everyday English they're squash (not berries), whereas to a botanist they're squash (and also berries).

Answer (score 1):

Each strand connected to a pumpkin seed is a [funiculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placentation#In_plants) (plural funiculi). The funuculus attaches the seed to the fruit placenta. This photo shows three areas of placenta, the spongy areas that the three clusters of seeds are around. The endocarp is the inner fruit layer; I'm not sure but here it either blends in to the mesocarp (the main flesh of the pumpkin) without a distinct boundary, or it helps make up the spongy tissue in the very center (or both!).